# What is the right way to navigate between fragments in BottomNavigationView?

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

**Problem in short:**

I have an `MainActivity` that holds `BottomNavigationView` and `FrameLayout` on top of it. `BottomNavigationView` has 5 tabs and when tab is clicked, I add some fragment on that `FrameLayout`. But, from some fragment, I need to open another fragment. From that another fragment, I need to open the other one. Every time when I need to show fragment, I notify MainActivity from fragment, that it needs to add the another one. Every fragment checks does its activity implement interface. And it is annoying.  So, if I have 100 fragments, MainActivity implements too many interfaces. It leads to boilerplate code. So, how to properly navigate between fragments if you have a lot?

**Problem in detail:**

Please, read problem in short section first.

As I've said I have `BottomNavigationView` that has 5 tabs. Let's call the fragments that responsible for each tab as `FragmentA`, `FragmentB`, `FragmentC`, `FragmentD`, `FragmentE`. I really know, how to show these fragments when tab is clicked. I just replace/add these fragments in activity. But, wait, what if you wanna go from `FragmentA` to `FragmentF`? After that from `FragmentF` to `FragmentG`? This is how I handle this problem: from `FragmentF` or `FragmentG` I notify `MainActivity` that I wanna change the fragment. But how they communicate with `MainActivity`? For this, I have interfaces inside of each fragment. MainActivity implements those interfaces. And here is problem. MainActivity implements too many interfaces that leads to boilerplate code. So, what is the best way to navigate through Fragments? I don't even touch that I also need to handle back button presses :)

**Here is how my code looks like:**

MainActivity implementing interfaces to change fragments if necessary:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DashboardFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
    PaymentFragment.BigCategoryChosenListener, PaymentSubcategoryFragment.ItemClickedListener, PayServiceFragment.OnPayServiceListener, ContactListFragment.ContactTapListener, P2PFragment.P2PNotifier
```

Here is my PaymentFragment's onAttach method for example:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof BigCategoryChosenListener) {
        listener = (BigCategoryChosenListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement BigCategoryChosenListener");
    }
}
```

And using this `listener` I notify activity to change fragment. And **in EACH** fragment I should do so. I don't think that it is best practice. So, is it ok or there is a better way?

Comment: Your approach is correct, but do you actually have 100 different types of fragments? Are you sure they can't be represented by a few fragments which simply update their content? It sounds very unlikely that you really need that many..

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin Thanks for response. Unfortunately, I didn't understand you very well. What do you mean by having few fragments? I have BottomNavigationView with 5 tabs and from each tab I can navigate to other fragments. You mean, that I need to have fragments inside fragments?

Comment: 5 tabs, each has one corresponding content fragment. Even if they are different, this is just one interface in activity with a method like `onTabClicked(int tab)`. Are all those 5 fragments navigable? When you navigate, can you generalize the logic somehow? Please give more details on what kind of content you show and what happens when you navigate inside. Thanks.

Comment: @abay - Well to me based on your description , you can have specific set of Fragments say for 5 tabs 5 fragements and can replace them as and when you wish. To control navigation amongst them have a Navigator for this purpose will helper methods for screen navigation. Like replaceFragment. Hope this helps.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin Updated question with more details

Comment: @Abhi Please, look to update question

Comment: abay - Ok thanks for detailed description. If I have to solve this scenario, I won't bother Mainactivity for interactions. Given that all your Fragment view are on depth level 1 . You can use a ScreenManager kind of helper class with Context(ActivityContext) as parameter for helper method replaceFragment. Hope I made it clear. Also your back stack navigation will work fine.

Comment: @abay thanks! So, if the problem is that there is too much code in the `MainActivity` then you can do what @Abhi said - move it to some helper class such as Navigator, just for improving readability. If you actually have that many fragments you will still have to write this logic somewhere, whether it's activity or navigator, doesn't really matter.

Comment: The only way to reduce amount of code would be to create some kind of mapping between fragments and create a generic method for replacing fragments which will figure out what fragment to populate when navigating down, depending on that mapping. But this will increase the complexity a lot, and most likely it is not worth it. I think it's totally fine to have a lot of code if it's doing one specific thing, navigation, and is written in a single place and is not spread out across your code base. I think simply moving the code to a helper class is a way to go.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin Thanks again. Let's give it a last try. I update questions inserting some code. Maybe it helps you to understand problem deeply and give another advices.

Comment: @Abhi I update questions putting some code. What do you think about that code? Is it ok?

Answer (score 1):

Ok What you need is something like this in activity where you would initialized on your BottomNavigationView.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {

               case R.id.menu_1://Handle menu click - 
                     //Call Navigator helper to replace Fragment to Fragment A
                     break;  
                case R.id.menu_2:
                    //Call Navigator helper to replace Fragment to Fragment B
                     break;

                case R.id.menu_3:
                   //Call Navigator helper to replace Fragment to Fragment C
                     break;
                  }
            return true;
        }
```

});

Comment: But replacing fragment means destroying previous fragment. It means when you press back, the previous fragment recreates and does unnecessary operations like HTTP requests

Comment: Well depends what you do there. Generally in correct programming approach the HTTP request would be fired from a presenter (MVP) never from fragment and fragment will show the data which is retrieved from server and cached. It also depends when (when is preseneter brought into action) is data fetched . Also say when concern target fragment is already in backstack of FragmentManager you can directly go to target fragment.